# Alternative for 'attribute_names' in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have been trying to build a backend admin , as written in Iain Hecker's tutorial: http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1 and I am trying to adapt it to Mongoid.

```
module Backend::ResourceHelper

  def attributes
    resource_class.attribute_names - %w(id created_at updated_at)
  end

end
```

With the above code, I was getting the following error:

```
undefined method `attribute_names' for Backend::User:Class
```

So, I tried the solution pointed out in this post: [How can I get all field names of the Mongoid Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004742/how-can-i-get-all-field-names-of-the-mongoid-document)

I tried using 'resource_class.fields.keys' instead of 'resource_class.attribute_names' but I end up with the following error:

Showing app/views/backend/resource/_index.html.haml where line #9

```
raised:undefined method `id' for [:where, {}]:Array
```

Extracted source (around line #9):

```
6: %th  
7: %tbody
8: - collection.each do |resource|
9: %tr[resource]
10: - attributes.each do |attr|
11: %td= resource.public_send(attr).to_s.truncate(20)
12: %td
```

I am new to Rails and I would really appreciate it if you could provide me some pointers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Contest.first.attributes.map { |attr, value| attr }
 => ["_id", "closing_on", "created_at", "description", "entries", "name"]
```